# Importing raster dataset in ArcSDE/PostgreSQL/Postgis database useable in QGIS and ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, enterprise-geodatabase

I want to import a raster dataset in my database (PostgreSQL 9.4, Postgis 2.1), the catch is that I also want the raster to be viewed in QGIS via a Postgis connection.

Importing feature classes in my database, I can simply use PG_GEOMETRY to make these readable in QGIS, but how does it work with a raster dataset?

Simply importing a raster via the ArcCatalog does not work.

Comment: Not possible -- There are no shared formats for this to happen. Esri has effectively decided that the performace of database storage is so poor as to not be worth their developers' effort to try to optimize (SDO_RASTER support has been deprecated as well)